# Mysql database been hacked. What to do now?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, database

My testing database has been hacked.  I am pretty sure it's hacked by an easily guessed test use admin credential.

After reading [How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server) I've got an idea of what to do, but the problem is how to do it.  I have tried looking to see what queries the hacker had used but since the `general_log` was turned off there isn't a log to see.

So far what I did is remove all unused accounts, set port access on AWS to my computer only.

What/and how could I do to make sure that I didn't leave any vulnerability open for the hacker to use? Also how do I ensure I removed everything the hacker has done without having a log?

Comment: You blow away the system and reinstall it. A lot less work for a test database.

Comment: He could have your OS passwords, too.